# Blink application icon in taskbar when javafx modal dialog loses focus

Tags: javafx

I am developing netbeans platform application.I have main window with a button.On clicking the button, a Javafx modal dialog (stage) will open.

Now,when the user clicks on any control eg:text field in main window,the modal dialog goes behind main window.If this is the behavior,I want to highlight(blink) the application icon in taskbar when dialog loses focus.Please help!Thanks

code:

```
            final Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlUi);
            dialogStage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            boolean atFirst = false;
      @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue) {
                if (!newPropertyValue) {
                    dialogStage.setIconified(true);
                    dialogStage.hide();
                }
                if (!atFirst) {
                    atFirst = true;
                    dialogStage.show();
                } else {
                    dialogStage.setIconified(true);
                    dialogStage.show();
                }
            }
        });
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialogStage.setResizable(true);
        dialogStage.centerOnScreen();
        dialogStage.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Can you post some code you have tried?

Comment: @ jhhoff02 I have added code.This I have tried for making application icon blink.Thanks!

Comment: You can set your initOwner method of dialogStage with primaryStage or mainStage. It is like: dialogStage.initOwner(mainStage). Please check "MBec" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `Stage` to be owner of modal dialog, then dialog will always be on top of `Stage`.

```
dialog.initOwner(stage);
```